# Why is my page reloading even though I have event.preventDefault (form handling jquery + node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using jQuery to asynchronously post my data to my db using node.js and express.js

Here is roughly what I am doing:

index.html:

```
<form id='mailer' action='/mail/new' method='post'>
  <input name='mycontent'/>
  <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

script.js:

```
$("#mailer").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('/mailer/new',{mycontent:mycontent});
});
```

app.js:

```
app.post("/mailer/new",function(){
  //insert into database
}
```

So it is essentially submitting to my database but ignoring the e.preventDefault because my page shows the loader wheel when I press submit

Comment: Handler might not be targeting the selector right... I'd try removing the `#` from your form `id='#mailer'` and then put quotes around your jQuery selector `$("#mailer").submit(...`

Comment: e.stopPropagation();

Comment: Sorry @mfink that was a typo in my code I actually do have it as "#mailer"

Comment: e.stopPropagation() is not making it work either. I have used preventDefault always in the past and it has worked. Not sure why its not working now

Comment: Can you verify that jQuery is loaded on the client side? If you put a `console.log('blah')` before the post statement, does it show up in the inspector just before the form submission?

Comment: I have verified that it is working, I have console logged a random class using console.log($(".randomclass")); and the console is showing the class [div.randomclass, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]

Answer (score 2):

1. As a commenter pointed out, you need to remove the hash `#` from the `id` attribute of your form:

   `<form id='mailer'...`
2. You need quotes around the element you're submitting. A JavaScript error occurs (`undefined` variable, most likely) and the form submits anyway before the `preventDefault()` runs.

   `$(#mailer).submit(function(e){...`

   Should be:

   `$('#mailer').submit(function(e){`

Comment: Also needs `#` removed from id in the html

Comment: The #mailer for jquery was a typo I have it as "#mailer" and the same goes for the html, in my html I have it as "mailer" not "#mailer".

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by console logging the event object. Turns out the event object (atleast while using jquery) doesn't have a 'preventDefault' function. But rather has an 'isPreventDefault()' function which takes in true or false.

I just replaced the e.preventDefault with e.isPreventDefault(true) and this fixed it and it is not reloading now

Comment: Interesting find. For a more common solution, you may also try `return false;` as your last line in the jQuery submit handler.